# Did not receive notification from Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I've downloaded blank project from 
[https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/new]Parse and connected my app to Parse as shown in the example, but when I send push from Parse.com nothing is recieved.

And I have that in logcat:

```
12-11 11:50:35.847 14420-14463/com.parse.starter D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.parse.com  return error = 0x8 >> <br>
12-11 11:50:35.877 14420-14463/com.parse.starter D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.parse.com get result from proxy >> <br>
12-11 11:50:35.884 14420-14463/com.parse.starter I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /52.0.55.235:443;LocalPort=48160(10000) <br>
12-11 11:50:35.884 14420-14463/com.parse.starter I/System.out: [CDS]connect[/52.0.55.235:443] tm:10
```

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask in your class?

Comment: No. I've just dowloaded example from site and change client ID and application ID. I know about network requests in asynctask. Where I should use asynctask?

Comment: Ok leave about AsyncTask.Did u add permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="org.moedelo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.moedelo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />`

Comment: Did you place the library in libs folder?

Comment: Problem solved after add in AndroidManifest.xml `<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Comment: Good! i said know if we add all in manifest and add library it will works like charm!